# Error when using LaTeX in Visual Studio Code: You don't have an extension for debugging LaTeX. Should we find a LaTeX extension in the Marketplace?

Tags: debugging, vscode, latex-workshop

When I try to run a tex file in VS Code, I get the error 'You don't have an extension for debugging LaTeX. Should we find a LaTeX extension in the Marketplace?' and cannot run the file. But when I try to find an extension to debug Latex through the filter @category:debuggers LaTeX I cannot find any extension either. I already have installed Latex Workshop, Raspberry Pi, and Strawberry Perl as a Youtube video recommended these 3 installations when working with Latex on VS Code. Can anyone explain the steps to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have installed `latex workshop` extension? If the answer is yes, then try `ctrl + alt + b` (`command + alt + b` if you are in a Mac). The “run” you are trying is for other languages